# Compiler warning when using AuthorizationFilters with async method calls

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I have a fairly controller that requires login in before being able to do any other calls. I have an authorization filter setup to deny access to method without being authenticated, but I'm trying to setup an override for the login method.

The issue is that the controller is using async calls, and thus produces a compiler warning about having to await it.

Here is the filter registration:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyAuthorizationFilter>()
    .AsWebApiAuthorizationFilterOverrideFor<MyController>(c => c.LoginAsync(null))
    .InstancePerRequest();
```

Warning is:

```
Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.
```

Inserting await in the expression and converting to an async lamba breaks the method definition, so that isn't an option here.

It *seems* to work alright, but I'd like confirmation that this is how it should be done, or that I'm way out.

Comment: `AsWebApiAuthorizationFilterOverrideFor` is looking for a `MethodInfo`. The method uses an expression tree to obtain it. You can't mix `await`/`async` with `expression tree` so you can't use it other way. Because this code won't be directly executed, I think there is no issue using this code. If you want to hide the warning, you can surround your code with `#pragma warning disable 4014` and `#pragma warning restore 4014`

Comment: @CyrilDurand that's what I thought. Would you mind posting your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AsWebApiAuthorizationFilterOverrideFor` needs a `MethodInfo`. In order to obtain it, the method ask for an expression tree and parse it to find the `MethodInfo`.

C# compiler doesn't know that the expression tree will only be used for parsing. So it display the CS4014 warning [Compiler Warning CS4014 (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873131.aspx).
To avoid this warning, the code require an `await`, so the correct code should be

```
 .AsWebApiAuthorizationFilterOverrideFor<MyController>(async c => await c.LoginAsync(null))
```

But due to the complexity of `await`/`async`, it is not possible to mix it with with expression tree.

Because this code won't be executed but only parsed, there is no issue with this code. 
If you want to hide the warning, you can surround your code with

```
#pragma warning disable 4014 // hide warning because this code won't be executed
builder.RegisterType<MyAuthorizationFilter>()
    .AsWebApiAuthorizationFilterOverrideFor<MyController>(c => c.LoginAsync(null))
    .InstancePerRequest();
#pragma warning restore 4014
```